# Jupyter notebook button widget: Remove all click handlers?

Tags: python-3.x, callback, widget, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

It seems (correct me if I'm wrong), that when I invoke `button.on_click(callback)`, the object `button` being an instance of `ipywidgets.Button`, the function `callback` is added to a list of click handlers. How can I access this list?

I would actually like to clear this list. If I could *find* the callback list (I can't!), I could apply `button.on_click(callback, remove=True)` for all registered callbacks.

Is there a better/more idiomatic way than the above to remove all click handlers from a button widget? My handlers are generated programmatically and I don't want to have to store references to all of them if I want to delete them later...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there is no method defined for this, I searched into their code and found where they are registering their callbacks. Here is how you can remove all click handlers -

```
button._click_handlers.callbacks = []
```